# Why is object's location is same, ( vector (0,0,0) ) in all frames of animation?

Tags: animation, objects, vertices, keyframes, coordinates

I have imported a human model mesh, with armature and animated it with mocap. What I exactly need is the position of its eyes at different frames.

```
              for f in frame_numbers:

                    eye_ob = bpy.data.objects[model+':Low-poly'] #eyes 
                    ob = bpy.data.objects[model]
                    REyeIdx=95 
                    LEyeIdx=47
                    scene.objects.active = eye_ob
                    scene.frame_set( f )
                    scene.update()                              
                    verts= eye_ob.data.vertices
                    print("right eyes ",verts[REyeIdx].co) #--this prints same value in all frames 
                    print("left eyes ", verts[LEyeIdx].co) #--this prints same value in all frames 
                    print("model pos" , ob.matrix_world.translation) #--this prints vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
                    print("eye pos" ,  eye_ob.matrix_world.translation) #--this prints vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

I am getting same 0,0,0 vector for object and its eye's positions. The coordinates of a specific vertex of eyes remains the same throughout the animation( not 0 vector). What could be the reason?  How can I fix it?  I saw related questions, but did not help.

Comment: You need to look at the pose bone locations.

Comment: Yes, pose bone works. but i need eye's location in specific, also ears and nose!

Comment: Add an empty with a vertex parent.  The `matrix_world.to_translation()` "should" work on empty.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What should be empty? I am new to blender scripting

Comment: [Add Object Empty](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/empties.html) and  [Parent to vertex](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#vertex-parent)

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind writing few lines of code for this?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/vertex-coordinate-after-pose-change

Comment: @lemon thank you so much. I had tried different things, only this worked. :D  Thanks again!